# What am I doing wrong in this? When the input is [1,2,3,null,5], output is supposed to be ["1->2->5","1->3"], but my output is ["1->2->5"]

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

When the input is [1,2,3,null,5], output is supposed to be ["1->2->5","1->3"], but my output is ["1->2->5"]. It seems like something weird is going on with self.arr. I tried deep copying self.arr to a temporary array and clearing self.arr before returning the temporary array, but that doesn't work as well.

The question is, given the root of a binary tree, return all root-to-leaf paths in any order.A leaf is a node with no children.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution(object):


    stringToAdd = ""
    arr = []
    end = True

    def binaryTreePaths(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        if self.end == True:
            self.arr = []
            self.end = False
    
        if root is None:
            self.end = True
            return None
    
        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            newString = self.stringToAdd
            self.stringToAdd += str(root.val)
            self.arr.append(self.stringToAdd)
            self.stringToAdd = newString
        elif root.left is None and root.right is not None:
            self.stringToAdd += str(root.val)
            self.stringToAdd += "->"
            self.binaryTreePaths(root.right)
        elif root.right is None and root.left is not None:
            self.stringToAdd += str(root.val)
            self.stringToAdd += "->"
            self.binaryTreePaths(root.left)
        elif root.right is not None and root.left is not None:
            self.stringToAdd += str(root.val)
            self.stringToAdd += "->"
            self.binaryTreePaths(root.right)
            self.binaryTreePaths(root.left)
    
        self.end = True
    
        return self.arr
```

Comment: Please include the part you are calling your class with input.

Comment: Hi, this is a leetcode question, so I don't have that class

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- The use of `self.end` is troublesome: it seems intended to reset the array on the solution instance when a new test case is run, but this is not going well. After every call of the function, `self.end` is set to true, but this does not really mark the end. There might still be other paths that are visited by a second recursive call. This is the reason why you only got one path instead of two. You should rethink this and better not rely on instance attributes.
- You have implemented some form of backtracking by shortening `self.stringToAdd` back to its previous value (`newString`), but this is only happening when the end of a path is reached. Yet this kind of backtracking/shortening should happen at *every* level where an alternative needs to be considered and a new recursion starts.
- I would suggest a more elegant way of working with these variables (the list `arr` and the path-string): have them only created when a leaf is encountered, and only enrich them at the time a recursive call **comes back**. This way you don't need any globals or instance attributes. You only need to get the list of paths that come back from recursion and prefix each of those with the current node.

Here is a version with that idea:

```
class Solution(object):
    def binaryTreePaths(self, root):

        if root.left is None and root.right is None:  # base case
            return [str(root.val)]  # return as if this is the only node 
        else:
            arr = []
            for child in root.left, root.right:
                if child:
                    for path in self.binaryTreePaths(child):
                        arr.append("{}->{}".format(root.val, path))
            return arr
```